# How can I group separate items in a list together?

Tags: python

I am very new to python.
I made a list(`mean1`) and let's say the output is,

```
2
3
4
5
```

the size of this should be 4, in my opinion, but the np.size returns below:

```
1
1
1
1
```

How can I group those separately splitted items into one group(array)? My purpose is to find out a minimum value by comparing the numbers(2,3,4,5) and its index. (so, the minimum value is 2, and index should be 0).
This is my code:

```
for i in range(0,151):
    mse=[]
    for e in eval_indices:

  #Define the evaluation set for the current fold
        eval_set= z[e]

  #exclude the upon parts indices from the 
  #whole array (similarly on the upon answers)
        mask_eval = np.ones(z.shape[0], bool)

  #Set indices of the eval set to false
        mask_eval[e] = False

  #Subset by the bool array:
        train_set = z[mask_eval]
  # Now find out w and mean value of MSEs of 10 evaluating subsets. 
        y=train_set[:,-1]
        x=train_set[:,:-1]
        I=np.identity(n=z.shape[1]-1, dtype=np.int8)
        w=np.linalg.inv((i*I)+(np.transpose(x)@x))@np.transpose(x)@y


        eval_y=eval_set[:,-1]
        eval_x=eval_set[:,:-1]
        mse_tst=1/(2*len(eval_set))*(np.transpose(eval_y-(eval_x@w))@(eval_y-(eval_x@w))) 
        mse.append(mse_tst)
        mean1=np.mean(mse)
    mean1=np.array(mean1)
           


    print(np.size(mean1))
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please share a minimum, reproducible example. We can't tell you what you're doing wrong if you don't share your code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: "but the np.size returns below" It would be helpful if we could see how you're using the function to get that output. It's also unclear on what your input structure is. Is it a list an array and 2d array? It would be helpful if you'd included some code that could provide insight into the task and where your approach is falling short.  See [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible, Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for more details.

Comment: @j1-lee Hi, I couldn't go to min function because I can't compare the numbers in which elements are separately in. What is reproducible function?

Comment: @j1-lee Yeah mean 1 is a collection of iteration results. Thus there are 150 items in mean1 list, and I want to compare the 150 items and find out the min value.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need a separate array:

```
mse = []
means = []
for e in eval_indices:
...
  mean1=np.mean(mse)
  means.append(mean1)
```

Then you'll have a list of all the means.